# Vue2 $router.replace() does not call mounted hook

Tags: vuejs2, hook, router

I have Nuxt Vue 2 app. There is a redirect in the mounted hook to the same route. The only difference in this route is query string. It looks like

```
mounted() {
    ...
    if( !isTokenOwner ) {
        const result = await this.$api.campaignNewShare.copyNewShare(this.newShareToken);
        localStorage.setItem(result.data.token, new Date().getTime());
        this.$router.replace({'name': 'campaigns-new', 'query': {token: result.data.token}});
        this.loading = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

It seems that Vue stays on the same page and only replace the url query string parameter. But I need to redirect to the new location with whole new lifecycle.

Can somebody tell me what really happened there after the replace() call? Why it does not trigger the real redirect? Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) says

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user
> navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance
> will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is
> more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a
> new one. However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the
> component will not be called.